# Move mails to folders with the sender's name

Tags: vba, outlook, directory

It is possible to create a rule which, for a sender, moves all the mails to the folder of your choice (for example, it creates a folder with the name of the sender).

If I want that for all the expeditors, I need to repeat the rule creation for each sender.

What I'd wish would be a macro "meta-rule" for each sender to have a folder with their name with the corresponding mails sorted.

I tried to start from the topic *[Outlook template rule to sort mails among directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32993611/outlook-template-rule-to-sort-mails-among-directories)*.

I wrote this:

```
Sub RulesForFolders(m As MailItem)
Dim fldr As Outlook.Folder
For Each fldr In GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders
    if fldr.Name Like m.SenderName Then m.MoveTo(SenderName)
    else folders.add(m.SenderName)
Next
Set fldr = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
'
' If desperate declare as variant


Private Sub RulesForFolders(m As mailItem)

Dim targetFldr As folder
Dim myRoot As folder

Dim i As Long

Set myRoot = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Debug.Print m.senderName

' This is often misused.
On Error Resume Next

' If folder exists the error is bypassed
' This is a rare beneficial use of On Error Resume Next
myRoot.folders.Add m.senderName

' Consider it mandatory to return to normal error handling
On Error GoTo 0

Set targetFldr = myRoot.folders(m.senderName)
m.Move targetFldr

End Sub


Private Sub RulesForFolders_test()

' Code requiring a parameter cannot run independently

Dim selItem As Object

' first select a mailitem
Set selItem = ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)

If selItem.Class = olMail Then
    RulesForFolders ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks niton, I try to applicate it and I tell you the feedback.

Comment: Hi there, I tried but it did not work.. I don't really know if I make anything wrong.. Should I put your code at macro 1 then put the code of Eugene in macro 2 then launch the macro 1 ?

Comment: I feel stuck because i think it's my limit, I don't really have a representation of the process of "call a sub from another instance"..

Comment: You call `Sub RulesForFolders(m As mailItem)` from `Sub RulesForFolders_test`. Select a mailitem then open the editor then run or F8 in `Sub RulesForFolders_test`.

Comment: Once you test `Sub RulesForFolders(m As mailItem)` assuming your setup allows the option to "call a script" in rules you would choose` RulesForFolders`.

Comment: Wow, this worked !!! Thanks ! Now I just need to adapt it to do that for all the mails in my inbox in one time.

Under  "Set selItem = ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)",
I added " For Each selItem In ActiveExplorer.Selection".

It seems to do the sort for a selection of many mails but it sorts them all in my main account/mail.. Even when i selected mails from another account/mail..

I think the problem is here : "Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)". I have a .fr and a .com, etc.. I woud need the macro to do it in the same mailspace..

Comment: Consider creating a question about determining an item's associated inbox.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd suggest starting from the `NewMailEx` event of the `Application` class which is fired when a new item is received in the Inbox. This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`. The `EntryIDsCollection` string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item. The `NewMailEx` event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the `EntryIDCollection` array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item.

To find the folder with a sender name you can iterate over all subfolders recursively:

```
Private Sub processFolder(ByVal oParent As Outlook.MAPIFolder)

        Dim oFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
        Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem

        For Each oMail In oParent.Items

        'Get your data here ...

        Next

        If (oParent.Folders.Count > 0) Then
            For Each oFolder In oParent.Folders
                processFolder oFolder
            Next
        End If
End Sub
```

Finally, I'd recommend delving deeper with VBA by starting from the [Getting started with VBA in Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/getting-started-with-vba-in-office) article.

---

You can also use the following code if you don't need to iterate over all folders:

```
Sub RulesForFolders(m As MailItem)
Dim fldr As Outlook.Folder
Dim new_fldr As Outlook.Folder
Dim ns as Outlook.Namespace
Dim inbox as Outlook.Folder 

Set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

For Each fldr In inbox.Folders
    if InStr(fldr.Name,m.SenderName) > 0 Then 
       m.MoveTo(fldr)
       Return       
    End If
Next

Set new_fldr = folders.add(m.SenderName)
m.MoveTo(new_fldr)

Set fldr = Nothing
Set new_fldr = Nothing
Set inbox = Nothing
Set ns = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I'd suggest posting separate questions in new threads so other readers could recognize questions and answers easily.

Comment: I'm sorry, i think I misspoke: the problem is the last code of this thread doesn't seem to execute correctly, nothing happens.. I have however tested simple macros and they worked, but this code doesn't..

Comment: I'd suggest running the code under the debugger attached.

Comment: Do you mean visualstudio debugger or just the VBA debugger provided with outlook ? Because when i use the last, nothing happens neiter..

Comment: Set a breakpoint and run the sub. If it is not running, check out Trust center settings in Outlook. Most probably macros are disabled in Outlook.

Comment: I have already enabled it, and if I code a popup the macro works..
It ignores my break points.
Do your code works on your outlook application ?

Comment: The takes a parameter, you need to define another sub without parameters where you may get an instance of the MailItem class and pass it to the method.

Comment: Yes, i think the answer of niton is supposed to do that, but it's not working either, it's my limit, i don't know how to do it and just paste the code seems not working..